# How to read information from JTextField in a loop

Tags: java, for-loop, jtextfield

How can i read the information from `JTextField`?

```
private class Caverage implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent AVR) {
        int num1 =Integer.parseInt(num_ofC.getText());
        JTextField[] coursg = new JTextField[num1];

        c.add(CAV);

        // Add JTextField if i Click the jbutton Click
        if (AVR.getSource() == Click) {
            for (int i =0;i<coursg.length;i++) {
                coursg[i] = new JTextField("",17);
                c.add(coursg[i]);
                setSize(700,240);
            }

            // Read JTextField if i click the jbutton CAV
            if (AVR.getSource() == CAV) {
                for (int i =0;i<coursg.length;i++) {
                    int num2 =Integer.parseInt(coursg[i].getText());
                    System.out.println(num2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your brackets. Your second `if` is inside the first `if` and `AVR.getSource()` cannot be `Click` and `CVR` at the same time.

Comment: i did that and it is still error          Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @amoi You haven't mentioned any `NullPointerException` in your question.